# Get source in constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to make a search with autocomplete, tell me how I can get in the constructor an array of label and results with axios get

```
new Autocomplete(input, {
  source: (response) => {
    axios.get('{{ route('api.autocomplete) }}', {
          params: {
            term: input.value
          }
        })
      .then(response => {
        return {
          label: response.data.name,
          results: response.data.children,
        }
      })
  },
  select: ({element}) => {
    alert(element);
  }
});


class Autocomplete {
  constructor(element, {
    source = () => {},
    select = () => {},
  }) {
    console.log(source);

  }
}
```

Instead of an array, it gives out a piece of axios request code

Comment: Why not separate objects for source and select?

Comment: You can't call async functions in a constructor, because it can't wait for them.

Comment: how to solve my problem then?

Comment: It sounds like `source` is a function that expects the current input as its parameter and returns a promise for the autocomplete entries. You will of course need to *call* that function, and you will also need to *wait* for the promise result (using `await` or `.then()`). Currently all you're doing is log the function object. You probably also shouldn't even try to get the array in the *constructor* of your `Autocomplete` object, but rather call the function when the user starts typing in the input.